# DispatcherTimer Error

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, oop, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App (WINRT).**

I am showing a **StatusBar**:

1. **MYAPP (WELCOME)**
2. **MYAPP (CONNECTED VIA WIFI)**
3. **MYAPP (CONNECTED VIA CELLULAR)**

If user is connected via Wifi, it shows "MYAPP (CONNECTED VIA WIFI)" and if user is connected via cellular, it shows "MYAPP (CONNECTED VIA CELLULAR)".

Also, it restores to default progressbartext "MYAPP (WELCOME)" after 5 seconds by using DispatcherTimer();

---

So,I execute **GetInternetConnectionProfile()** , returns **_connectedVia**, passing to **GetInternetConnectionProfile(_connectedVia)** function in Constructor or OnNavigatedTo.

```
Connectivity.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
StatusBarClassObject.StatusBarGenerator(_connectedVia);
```

Everything works fine till first execution of page.

Now, everytime a **network change hanppens** (Wifi to cellular or viceversa or wifi to none, etc), it executes **NetworkStatusChanged eventhandler** with same process as in constructor.

```
    NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += new NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler((n) => Connectivity.GetInternetConnectionProfile());

   NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += new NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler((n) => StatusBarClassObject.StatusBarGenerator(_connectedVia));
```

But the problem is that:
`StatusBarCloseTimer = new DispatcherTimer();` is giving me error this time. First execution of this works fine.

**"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))"**

I tried to use:

```
await CoreDispatcherObject.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
         DispatcherTimerInit();
        });



private void DispatcherTimerInit()
            {
        //  throw new NotImplementedException();
            StatusBarCloseTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            StatusBarCloseTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000);
            StatusBarCloseTimer.Tick += StatusBarCloseTimer_Tick;
            }
```

But now `StatusBarCloseTimer.Start();` is giving me same error:
**"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))"**

Comment: How about also calling Start() through Dispatcher? This error obviously means you're calling something from a wrong thread.

Comment: Solved: await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
   {}

Answer (score 2):

Solved: await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.N‌​ormal, () => {}